# Sublime text 3 Notepad++ theme

Tags: themes, sublimetext3

Does anyone know exact steps for adjusting notepad++ theme or look in sublime text 3.
There is one [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/sublime-3-notepad-theme/) which is not completely clear to me, and I am looking for some other solution.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MattDMo this is a how-to question and has a good answer. SO Policeman.

Comment: @Pawel absolutely I'm an SO policeman. Without the vigilance of dedicated community moderators such as myself (somewhat different from the ♦ mods) maintaining a very high standard of quality, Stack Overflow would turn into Yahoo Answers. As for this particular question, SO is *not* a tutorial site, and is not a resource for finding tutorials. My comment above is taken verbatim from a close reason, I didn't just make it up on my own. If you want to learn more about how the site works, spend some time on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone already made whole theme.
Here https://gist.github.com/rafaelmussi/3743237 is theme code. It says for sublime text 2, but it also work for sublime text 3.

Installation steps:

1) Open Sublime text and go to: Preferences->Browse packages... or on your hard disc go to: \AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages.

2) Create there some folder where you want to put your theme file, or you can put it in some of already created folder with other themes.

3) Create file Nodepad.tmTheme and put code from github link above into file.

4) Copy file in new created folder or some other folders with themes.

5) Open Sublime text 3 editor, go to: Preferences->Settings-User

6) Reference your new created theme here. Something like:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/NotepadTheme/Nodepad.tmTheme",
}
```

save and that is it.

Comment: Note - this color scheme is approximately the same... you will notice quite a few differences though (e.g. function names are blue instead of pink, and text in quotation marks is purple instead of gray etc.).